# sum integer and float in R

Tags: r, integer, sum, double

I would like to sum an integer and a very small floating point number like these

```
> int_number <- 1443622469
> float_number <- 0.00005676
```

and I want the result to be displayed in its entirety like this:

```
# 1443622469.00005676
```

Instead if I sum these two numbers in R:

```
> int_number + float_number
```

I get this result:

```
[1] 1443622469
```

Where am I wrong?

I tried to use `options(digits=8)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not use enough digits for the printing:

```
R> int_number <- 1443622469; float_number <- 0.00005676
R> print(int_number + float_number, digits=17)
[1] 1443622469.0000567
R>
```

But be aware that you are at the edge of what is still distinguishable under floating point arithmetic at double precision:

```
R> identical(int_number + float_number, 
+            int_number + float_number + 0.0000001)
[1] TRUE
R>
```